# Looking for short story about human outpost on alien world with dangerous native animals/insects

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Read this years ago (From 50's or 60's?) in Analog about a fortified compound/outpost on an alien world where the humans were in an escalating (and failing) arms race agains the local animal/insect population.  The natives became more deadly as the humans tried to develop better defenses.  One member of the outpost crashes in another area of the planet, expecting instant death, but finds the locals there non-threatening as they were only reacting to the violence of the outpost.  Looking for title and author.

Comment: Not an answer, but this question reminded me of this short story. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student_Body_(short_story). And here is a link to it - http://www.gutenberg.org/files/31815/31815-h/31815-h.htm

Answer (score 16):

Are you sure it was a short story? [Deathworld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathworld) by Harry Harrison matches your description, but it's a novel.

Comment: I think that's it.  Wikipedia says Deathworld was first published as a serialized novel in Analog in 1960, so that makes sense.  Thanks so much!  This has been bugging me for YEARS!

Answer (score 1):

*Deathworld* it is.

That novel is available free:
http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/28346

Also, the sequel:
*The Ethical Engineer*
http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/30964

Comment: There are three books, plus at least one short story (called The Mothballed Spaceship or something like that) set in that canon.