# Sci Fi novel possibly from the 70s on high gravity world

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for a science fiction novel I have read more than 20 years ago and which is possibly part of a series.

I cannot remember the exact story line but it involved a guy from earth who came to a colonial world with higher gravity than earth. Due to the higher gravity the human colonists on this world were much stronger than people from earth. The guy from earth made friends with some of the colonist and ended up staying on the planet which resulted in him also developing stronger physical powers albeit not as much as the people who were born on the planet. 
The novel was not a space opera type but rather an action novel however as I stated before I cannot remember the exact storyline.

Have been googling a lot but was unable to come up with the title of that novel or series of books.

Comment: There are a lot of novels involving higher gravity worlds. Can you think of anything else about the book that might jog peoples memories? Character names or place names, or any memorable plot points?

Comment: [Deathworld?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45526/looking-for-short-story-about-human-outpost-on-alien-world-with-dangerous-native/45527#45527) [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathworld)

Comment: There's also [Jinx](https://larryniven.fandom.com/wiki/Jinx) from Larry Niven's Known Space milieu.

Comment: @Kenster Jason DinAlt was my immediate thought as well; you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys! It was indeed Deathworld! Really happy to have found out there is actually three novels in the series! Got myself a used volume including all three novels and looking forward to a lot of reading pleasure now! Thanks again guys! Great community!

Answer (score 12):

Could it be "Deathworld 1" by Harry Harrison?

> The planet was called Pyrrus...a strange place where all the beasts,
>   plants and natural elements were designed for one specific purpose: to
>   destroy man. The settlers there were supermen...twice as strong as
>   ordinary men and with milli-second reflexes. They had to be. For their
>   business was murder... It was up to Jason dinAlt, interplanetary
>   gambler, to discover why Pyrrus had become so hostile during man's
>   brief habitation..

Or there is "Stainless Steel Rat" series from the same author, with references to high-gravity world.

Comment: Thank you so much! I looked it up and it is Deathworld! Found out there's actually three novels in the series. Just got myself a used volume including all three novels and can't wait to start reading!